# How to add columns to my data frame, including the counts of another columns , for two different column, in R?

Tags: r, count

I need to count two different columns in a data frame and add the values as two new columns.

In the example below, I want to count x and y

```
ID  l   x   y
1   s   1   E
1   s   2   NA
1   s   3   E
1   s   4   E
1   s   5   E
2   ss  1   NA
2   ss  2   E
2   ss  3   E
3   m   1   NA
3   m   2   E
3   m   3   NA
3   m   4   NA
3   m   5   E
3   m   6   E
3   m   7   NA
4   mm  1   E
4   mm  2   E
```

and I need the output to look like the below:

```
ID  l    n.x    n.y
1   s    5      4
2   ss   3      2
3   m    7      3
4   mm   2      2
```

How can I use count ()? or other codes?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach. You can `group_by` your `ID` column, and count rows that is not `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, l) %>% 
  summarize(n.x = sum(!is.na(x)), n.y = sum(!is.na(y)), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID l       n.x   n.y
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1     1 s         5     4
2     2 ss        3     2
3     3 m         7     3
4     4 mm        2     2
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it helped. I just edited as follow:
  
  df %>% 
  group_by(ID, l) %>% 
  summarize(n.x = length((x)), n.y = sum(!is.na(y))